# Pull branch from Team Foundation Service to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, git-branch, git-pull, azure-devops

I'm working on a project with 2 others, and we're using Visual Studio 2012 with Git and Team Foundation Service.

I'm able to clone the repository from TFS to my machine, however I can't get a separate development branch to pull as well, while I'm able to see it on the TFS website.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found it, apparently it's a bug in Visual Studio Tools for Git:

> To summarize this issue: Visual studio tools for git does not automatically show new published branches in coworker machines. With version 8.5.1. you have to remove the tagopt = --tags option from .git/config, then go to command line and do a `git fetch` and then a `git checkout -b <newBranchName> origin/<newBranchName>`.

(Source: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c/view/Discussions/2

Title : "Can't see remote branches"; written April 25, 2013 by HectorCruz)

Comment: Thanks for this, I wasn't able to get my remote branches to appear either even on the latest version of git for VS (0.9.5.0)...FYI for anyone else reading this:  tagopt = --tags isn't set by default in the latest version of the tools, but it still doesn't seem to like fetching remote branches (which really sucks)...just checkout the branch by command line as stated above and you are fine

Comment: A bug? You just go to new branch and it shows the remote branch in the drop down list. Git for tfs doesn't list remote branches under Branches, it shows your local branches. Out of the box you should see master because you cloned the repo at origin/master.

Answer (score 4):

Old topic, but I found an other way: Use sourcetree. When downloaded and installed, connect to the git repository and find the branch you would like to check out under **Remotes**... And check it out (right  mouse button -> checkout origin/**name branch**)

If you have your project open in Visual Studio it will reload the project based on the code in the branch. The branch is also visible in Team Explorer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Amazingly, this is still an issue in VS2013. Can be sorted quickly as you suggest by checking out branches via the command line or a client.

Comment: Yup. Try to go back a few versions in the file versioning... I stopped using Git and moved back to my own TFS server. Freedom at last!

Comment: Still an issue in 2015. `git checkout mybranchname` sorted it though and Team Explorer picked up the changes as soon as I did so.